# Postgresql is not running

Tags: postgresql, psql

I recently installed Postgresql and created a couple of databases, but when I tried adding a table to one of my databases I got this error message:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?e here
```

How can I resolve this? I tried stepping through various solutions:

```
$ rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
$ brew services restart postgresql
```

But got this in response:

```
rm: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what `brew services list` tell you about postgres?

Comment: `psql` is the Postgres command line client, your issue is with the install of the Postgresql server itself. I changed the post to reflect this.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but how did you install Postgres - definitely via homebrew, not Postgres.app or similar?